# How can I get a process starting and ending time in android

Tags: android

I want to get starting and ending time of a process in android. I tried to use process command PS but in android it doesn't provide any process time. In Linux OS we can get a process starting time but this command doesn't work with android. Can anybody help me.

Comment: what kind of process you will monitor?

Comment: @Veaceslav: Thanks for reply , I want to show a list of all running processes with start time and end time.

Answer (score 0):

If you desire to find time taken some process you can use that:

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();

// here you write your code

long endTime = System.nanoTime();
System.out.println("Took "+(endTime - startTime) + " ns");
if you want time in ms do : (endTime - startTime)/0.000001
```

Comment: @redIntet : Thanks for reply ,actually I need the start and end time of other running processes.

Comment: in the start of your process before you put your code you can create  a startTime like I show you in the code then you write your code and create a endTime when process  finishing

Comment: I want other running processes start and end time.

Comment: I need more informations to  understand what you want, can you put your code ?